# How to replace many .mbt files with encoding UTF-8 BOM to UTF-8 with powershell

Tags: powershell, encoding

i have many files with .mbt extension in a directory and currently its time consuming for my colleagues to edit each file with notepad++ to change the encoding from UTF-8 BOM to UTF-8 since these files are further imported into software and doesnt work with encoding UTF-8 BOM.

So i found one powershell script which replaces the file specified in the script with new file with correct encoding, but as it is this doesnt solve my issue and due to my lack of knowledge in powershell scripting i cant figure out how to make it replace the file with another without changing its name, but only the encoding and do it for all files in specified directory.

This is the current code that does what i explained:

```
function Remove-BomFromFile ($OldPath, $NewPath)
{
  $Content = Get-Content $OldPath -Raw
  $Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False
  [IO.File]::WriteAllLines($NewPath, $Content, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)
}
$Path = "C:\Users\slavkovs\Desktop\test\Z_00154_.mbt"
$NewPath = "C:\Users\slavkovs\Desktop\test\Z_00154_New.mbt"
Remove-BomFromFile -OldPath $Path -NewPath $NewPath

[CmdletBinding()]
param(  
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$path,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$dest = $path,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$encoding
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making use of the fact that .Net method `.WriteAllText()` of the [IO.File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file) class writes UTF-8 without BOM by default, you could use this:

```
$rootDirectory = 'D:\Test'    # path where the .mbt files are to be found
Get-ChildItem -Path $rootDirectory -Filter '*.mbt' -File | ForEach-Object {
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($_.FullName, ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName)))
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, much appreciated!! Thank you!